# Ionic2 and 3 Geolocation Error: Only secure origins are allowed, Error getting location and not working on device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Okay, Here is what happened, i have tried so many times to get geolocation working on an android device but nothing is happening instead it shows a **white screen**. I decided to test with an emulator by running `ionic cordova run android -l -c` then i discovered that it throws an exception  ***Only secure origins are allowed***. Then i tried using a solution i got from someone `(platform.ready().then(() => { )` before calling geolocation getcurrentPosition, I built the app for android and tested, it still shows a **white screen**. I ran with emulator and the exception changed to ***console log: Error getting location*** , I really need help, **please** anyone.

**I run ionic 3.4.0 with npm 5.0.3 on Node.js 7.8.0**

### Home.ts

```
getMapLocation() {

   var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 5000
    };


    /* Ensure the platform is ready */
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     console.log("platfrom is ready");

    /* Perform initial geolocation */
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude)
        this.Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.Longitude = position.coords.longitude;

     var pos = {
              lat: this.Latitude,
              lng: this.Longitude
            };

    this.location = pos;

     this.getMap(this.Latitude, this.Longitude);

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', err);
    });
})


}
```

### Config.Xml

```
<universal-links>
        <host name="tgp38.app.goo.gl" scheme="https" />
        <host name="taxi-59a68.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
            <path url="/__/auth/callback" />
        </host>
    </universal-links>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.8.101:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.8.103:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.8.102:8100" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-browsertab" spec="^0.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-stripe" spec="^1.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-universal-links-plugin" spec="^1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^3.6.5" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.playheavens.taxihub" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="tgp38.app.goo.gl" android:scheme="https"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="taxi-59a68.firebaseapp.com" android:scheme="https" android:path="/__/auth/callback"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$NFCStateChangedReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you found a solution @Chinedu?

Answer (score 3):

There is problem with 'livereload'. Google's new security rules are now only allowing `https` ports.

So, if you are running in the browser try using https://localhost:8100. and if you are running in device run it without `livereload` option.

Comment: Any options to get it to work with Ionic DevApp? I've tried --no-livereload on there but still can't get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try again using [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) in your browser.

It allows to you request any site with ajax from any source, no matter http/https discrepancies and the like. Practically adds the `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the response.

Please keep in mind that this is a band-aid solution for development only. It is your server actually that has to be configured to respond with the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` header, preferably with a more specific value than `*`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this is not going to solve my problem in any way. I need a solution to a problem regarding ionic 2 geolocation not working on an android device. It works well on chrome already.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood. As I said in my answer, it is your server actually that has to be configured to respond with the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` header, preferably with a more specific value than `*`, in order for this to be solved (on all platforms, mobile and pc). The reason I offered this quick band-aid solution is because it allows you to keep developing in the browser until you actually fix the issue in your server's configuration. Don't forget that both on a pc, but also on ios and android cordova apps still run in a browser (stripped down webview to be exact).

Comment: Thanks, but i think i found the solution.

Comment: Which is? You should share solutions with others, not only your problems.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Shreenil's answer, this can be caused by running on an Android emulator with the --livereload option as well as the -lc option.

tl;dr

Remove --livereload and -lc options